# OptionSetValue cannot be serialized using ODataMediaTypeFormatter

Tags: c#, visual-studio, asp.net-web-api, odata, dynamics-crm-2011

I am running a WebApi 2.0 Server trying to return an odataset, and when requesting this:

http://localhost:5001/mydatasource/api/v2/AccountSet?$filter=AccountNumber eq '142530'&$select=AccountNumber,AccountId

I am getting the following exception:

> {   "odata.error": {
>       "code": "",
>       "message": {
>         "lang": "en-US",
>         "value": "An error has occurred."
>       },
>       "innererror": {
>         "message": "'Microsoft.Crm.Sdk.Data.Services.OptionSetValue' cannot be serialized using the ODataMediaTypeFormatter.",
>         "type": "System.Runtime.Serialization.SerializationException",
>         "stacktrace": "   at System.Web.Http.OData.Formatter.Serialization.ODataEntityTypeSerializer.CreateStructuralProperty(IEdmStructuralProperty
>   structuralProperty, EntityInstanceContext entityInstanceContext)\r\n
>   at
>   System.Web.Http.OData.Formatter.Serialization.ODataEntityTypeSerializer.CreateStructuralPropertyBag(IEnumerable`1
>   structuralProperties, EntityInstanceContext entityInstanceContext)\r\n
>   at
>   System.Web.Http.OData.Formatter.Serialization.ODataEntityTypeSerializer.CreateEntry(SelectExpandNode
>   selectExpandNode, EntityInstanceContext entityInstanceContext)\r\n
>   at
>   System.Web.Http.OData.Formatter.Serialization.ODataEntityTypeSerializer.WriteEntry(Object
>   graph, ODataWriter writer, ODataSerializerContext writeContext)\r\n
>   at
>   System.Web.Http.OData.Formatter.Serialization.ODataEntityTypeSerializer.WriteObjectInline(Object
>   graph, IEdmTypeReference expectedType, ODataWriter writer,
>   ODataSerializerContext writeContext)\r\n   at
>   System.Web.Http.OData.Formatter.Serialization.ODataFeedSerializer.WriteFeed(IEnumerable
>   enumerable, IEdmTypeReference feedType, ODataWriter writer,
>   ODataSerializerContext writeContext)\r\n   at
>   System.Web.Http.OData.Formatter.Serialization.ODataFeedSerializer.WriteObjectInline(Object
>   graph, IEdmTypeReference expectedType, ODataWriter writer,
>   ODataSerializerContext writeContext)\r\n   at
>   System.Web.Http.OData.Formatter.Serialization.ODataFeedSerializer.WriteObject(Object
>   graph, Type type, ODataMessageWriter messageWriter,
>   ODataSerializerContext writeContext)\r\n   at
>   System.Web.Http.OData.Formatter.ODataMediaTypeFormatter.WriteToStream(Type
>   type, Object value, Stream writeStream, HttpContent content,
>   HttpContentHeaders contentHeaders)\r\n   at
>   System.Web.Http.OData.Formatter.ODataMediaTypeFormatter.WriteToStreamAsync(Type
>   type, Object value, Stream writeStream, HttpContent content,
>   TransportContext transportContext, CancellationToken
>   cancellationToken)\r\n--- End of stack trace from previous location
>   where exception was thrown ---\r\n   at
>   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task
>   task)\r\n   at
>   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task
>   task)\r\n   at
>   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.GetResult()\r\n   at
>   System.Web.Http.Tracing.ITraceWriterExtensions.d__24.MoveNext()\r\n---
>   End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown
>   ---\r\n   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task
>   task)\r\n   at
>   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task
>   task)\r\n   at
>   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.GetResult()\r\n   at
>   System.Web.Http.Owin.HttpMessageHandlerAdapter.d__13.MoveNext()"
>       }   } }

Why would it be trying to serialize an optionset if I am simply requesting 2 fields which are not optionsets? This is for CRM 2011.

**What is the proper way of serializing an odata optionset?**

Comment: What version of CRM are you using?

Comment: @pen2 im using crm 2011